# is it possible to add table metadata in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Forgive my ignorance, but I'm wondering if there is a way to specify metadata for a table in PostgreSQL that I don't want it to be as a field in that table. For instance, if I want to add a Description field for that table, creation Time, etc...

I know I can do this using extra tables, but I'd prefer having not to do this, to be honest. I've digged in the official PostgreSQL docs, but there's nothing there besides looking in information_schema.tables, where I guess I'm not allowed to modify anything.

Any clues? Otherwise, I guess I'll have to create a few more tables to handle this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's the comment field:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table IS 'Yup, it's a table';
```

In current versions the comment field is limited to a single text string. There's been discussion of allowing composite types or records, but AFAIK no agreement on any workable design.

You can shove JSON into the comments if you want. It's a bit dirty, since it'll show up as the `Description` column in `\d+` output in `psql`, etc, but it'll work.

```
craig=> COMMENT ON TABLE test IS 'Some table';
COMMENT
craig=> \d+
                         List of relations
 Schema |         Name         |   Type   | Owner |    Size    | Description 
--------+----------------------+----------+-------+------------+-------------
 public | test                 | table    | craig | 8192 bytes | Some table
```

You can get the comment from SQL with:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.obj_description('test'::regclass, 'pg_class');
```

Comments can also be added on other objects, like columns, data types, functions, etc.

If that doesn't fit your needs you're pretty much stuck with a side table for metadata.

People regularly request table metadata like creation time, etc, but nobody tends to step up with a workable plan for an implementation and the time and enthusiasm to carry it through to the finish. In any case the most common request is "last modified time", which is pretty horrible from a performance point of view and difficult to get right in the face of multi-version concurrency control, transaction isolation rules, etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the ultra-detailed response. I guess COMMENT will work for description purposes. I guess I can also insert a timestamp there and then use it for "Table creation time". I don't get the whole idea of the last modified thingy...I think that having a field in the table for each row with the timestamp of its creation/modification and ordering based on that field should suffice...Altough not very efficient if not needed obviously...Thanks Craig! Nice answer!

Comment: @AlejandroVK With the matter of "last modified" - it's usually people who want to see which tables have recent changes without having to scan the table heaps. I don't really get it either, but it seems to be a common request.

Comment: Another use case that comes to my mind would be to let application code store relevant state on a table. E.g. I am using a table that stores events. Applications process this event stream as they wish, so it would have been nice if they were able to store an id/timestamp of their last processed event directly on the table.

Comment: @sthzg Just use another table. (Ab)using comments for that is a really bad idea. They are just stored in a system catalog anyway.

Comment: @CraigRinger I agree, actually I didn't consider using table-comments for this. It was more a comment on how I initially came here by searching if there was a mechanism for storing arbitrary table-related data somewhere on that particular table instead of inside a side-table.

Comment: Comments can be added easily via pgadmin - right click table, properties - Comments and then they will show up in QGIS under the Layer Properties - Information.